# Array of custom object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, model-view-controller

I'm new to JavaScript and ran into an issue creating an array of custom objects. 
I'm trying to apply the MVC concept. So in my Model I try to create a 'Node' object like this:

```
interFace.createNode = function(name) {
    debug('createNode');
    this.name = name;
    this.childNodes = [];
    ...
    return this
};
```

In my Controller I have a function where I create new nodes dynamically and add them to the childNodes array of the parent node like so:

```
parent_node.childNodes.push(Model().createNode("Node " + getNodeCount());
```

Push always returns 1, a subsequent call to length always 0. If I just push an integer value and not a node object the code works fine and the array grows as expected. 
Basically what I want is to create Node-objects dynamically (like new Node() in Java) and add those objects to an array of Nodes. But I suspect that my understanding of objects in JS is flawed by my experience in OO programming. 
 
Any help on how to resolve this issue is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
interFace.createNode = function(name) {
    debug('createNode');
    var node = {};
    node.name = name;
    node.childNodes = [];
    ...
    return node;
};
```

or, something like this:

```
interFace.createNode = function(name) {
    debug('createNode');
    return new interFace.Node(name);
};

interFace.Node = function(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.childNodes = [];
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes, yes that's what I want indeed. thank you very much!

Comment: No problem!  Javascript 'constructors' are notoriously unintuitive.

Comment: I agree :) Is it bad pratice to use JS like that (applying OO-patterns to  JS)?

Comment: Definitely not!  OO in JS is unintuitive at first, but very powerful once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of creating objects in JS use of OOP principles such as prototypes and literals, etc.

With regard to your question and the task you are going to achieve, following is a literal wrapper where you can populate a node object in static nature.Since you are invoking this method dynamically to create nodes.

var nodeHanlder = {

```
create : function(name){ 
        return {
        name : name,
        childNodes : []
    }
}
```

};

var node = nodeHanlder.create("Node 1");

this will return object...
to access properties,

//node.name;
//node.childNodes;